# Residuals and AIC

Tags: regression, econometrics, residuals, model-evaluation, aic

AIC is normally calculated using the maximum likelihood, so you must have some probability distribution to work with. But I saw some formulas using the sum of squared residuals or the mean absolute deviation.

From my understanding the formula using the sum of squared residuals is valid when your data is normally distributed, but what about the one using the  absolute deviations from the realized values?

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} | \text{predicted}_i - \text{realized}_i |$

What I mean by valid is it serves the purpose of the AIC, meaning getting an assessment of model performance AND complexity.
If I take the example of a quantile regression, the likelihood is based on the assymetric Laplace distribution. If I use this sum and try to minimize it and then input it into my AIC will it still be valid for quantile regression model selection purposes? Why?

And more generally in which cases to we have an equivalence between likelihood maximization and some form of residual minimization?

Is there some paper online discussing the relationship between residuals and likelihood for regression models?

Comment: Which MAD do you have in mind?  There are several!  (They vary on how you interpret "M" -- median or mean -- for finding the location and estimating the average deviation from that location.)

Comment: It is indeed ambiguous, I guess it stems from my lack of understanding, I'm gonna try to clarify, for  a median regression I would use median absolute deviation since the estimate is the conditional median. So just the sum of absolute residuals, same for any x quantile regression. And my question in that case, is whether this will give me a reliable AIC when I input this deviation in the logarithm of the AIC instead of the likelihood.
Similar to the mean case: AIC = n * ln(SSE/n) + 2 * k", but with absolute deviations from the predicted this time.

Comment: @FaresDjerourou, *I would use median absolute deviation since the estimate is the conditional median. So just the sum of absolute residuals, same for any x quantile regression.* These two sentences seem to contradict each other; sum is related to mean, not median.

Comment: @Richard Hardy Bad phrasing, I meant the residuals absolute difference between realized quantiles and predicted quantiles.

Comment: Then what does M stand for in MAD?

Comment: @RichardHardy It stands for mean in my original post, L1 norm of Predicted-Realized. Not the median of the residuals.

Comment: Please edit your post to make it clear to any readers what you are referring to with "MAD."

Comment: It should be clearer now.